# calculus optimization minimum value

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, trigonometry, optimization

in any triangle ABC compute the minimum value of:
$\sqrt{1-\sin(A)\sin(B)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(B)\sin(C)}+\sqrt{1-\sin(C)\sin(A)}$
that was my tray where is mistakes:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint.

Use (in the standard notation) $$\sqrt{1-\sin\alpha\sin\beta}\geq\frac{c}{a+b}.$$
Because it's $$(a-b)^2(a+b-c)^2(a+b+c)^2\geq0.$$

Comment: you mean that:$\sqrt{1-\sin(A)\sin(B)}\geq\frac{c}{a+b},\sqrt{1-\sin(B)\sin(C)}\geq\frac{b}{a+c},\sqrt{1-\sin(C)\sin(A)\geq\frac{c}{a+b}$ by adding we get:$\frac{c}{a+b}+\frac{b}{c+a}+\frac{a}{b+c}\geq\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: Yes, of course. After this use Nesbitt

Answer (score 0):

[image]

my tray and solution i want to know where is the mistakes and if there another solution

Comment: Typeset mathematical terms using MathJax rather than posting image. [Here's the tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Also, you should include this in the question itself.

Comment: How can i complete above@ solution in correct way